# How to repair errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, subprocess, ipython

```
<pre>import os, sys, codecs
from collections import defaultdict
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
bigLetters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def countLetters(file):
    results = defaultdict(int)
    for line in file:
        for char in line:
            if char.lower() in letters:
                c = char.lower()
                results[c] += 1
    return results

def main():
    file = codecs.open('szyfrogram.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
    content = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    dictionary = countLetters(content)

    most_popular = (max(dictionary, key=dictionary.get))
    shift_for_a = 122 - ord(most_popular.lower()) + 1
    saveDecoded(content, shift_for_a,'results_decoded.txt')

def saveDecoded(encoded, shift,file_output):
    decoded = ''
    for line in encoded:
        line = line.strip('\n') 
        for char in line:
            decoded = decoded + move(char,shift)
    output = open(filr_output,mode = 'w')
    output.write(decoded)
    output.close

def move(letter,shift):
    moveletter = letter
    if letter in letters:
        lower_range = 96
        top_range = 122
        moveCharLetters = ord(letter) + shift
        if moveCharLetters > top_range:
            moveCharLetters = lower_range + moveCharLetters-top_range
            moveletter = chr(moveCharLetters)     
        else:
            moveletter = chr(moveCharLetters)    
    elif letter in bigLetters:
        lower_range = 64
        top_range = 90
        moveCharLetters = ord(letter) + shift
        if moveCharLetters > top_range:
            moveCharLetters = lower_range + moveCharLetters-top_range
            moveletter = chr(moveCharLetters)    
        else:
            moveletter = chr(moveCharLetters)       
    else:
        moveletter = letter
    return moveletter

print('countLetters')
main()<code>
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\waldemar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Rot14.py", line 61, in 
        main()
      File "C:\Users\waldemar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Rot14.py", line 18, in main
        content = file.readlines()
      File "C:\Users\waldemar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\codecs.py", line 706, in readlines
        return self.reader.readlines(sizehint)
      File "C:\Users\waldemar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\codecs.py", line 615, in readlines
        data = self.read()
      File "C:\Users\waldemar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\codecs.py", line 501, in read
        newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 28: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Could you include your code as text in the post (just indent it another 4 characters so the formatter makes it a nice neat block) instead of having it linked as images.

Comment: Include the code in your question.

Comment: Are you sure your source file is utf-8 encoded, and not latin1 or something else?

Comment: Yes I am sure. If we use generator from website http://www.rot-n.com. We use text encoding:Od godziny zerowej mam wachtę na Morzu Lewantyńskim. Idziemy po jasnej
smudze roztopionego księżycowego srebra. Kurs nasz w tej chwili etc.This text is in polish.
prowadzi prosto na księżyc. Taka noc rozmarzy każdego… Na mostek
wchodzi nieśmiało młoda para. Ona, bardzo rozmarzona, pyta: - Proszę
pana, czy my możemy tu pozostać? Tutaj jest bardzo ładnie. Zasadniczo
na mostku nie może przebywać

Comment: I'm not sure that website's `rot14` will be meaningful for a non-ASCII text. It needs to order all the letters in the alphabet properly, and a naive website may not know anything about the alphabet used for Polish text. Thanks to Unicode it probably won't crash or render wingdings, but it may give you nonsense.

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `code` You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input file is not UTF-8, or you would not get an error on `content = file.readlines()`.

If you save the input file correctly as UTF-8, then another error is needing to write the output file in UTF-8 as well:

```
output = open(file_output,mode = 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

Then the output file contains:

```
Od godziny zerowej mam wachtę na Morzu Lewantyńskim.
```

Another thing to note is `codecs.open` isn't needed for Python 3.  The output file, for example, just uses the Python 3 built-in `open`.

Comment: Yes you are right. My teacher told me I must use codes.open. I still get errors. Program still doesn't work.

Comment: What is bad in my questions.